# Drawing a XY axis with categories

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Can anybody help me reproduce such a figure:

[image]

I succesfully reproduced most of it. But I would need to help with one small detail:

How can I put: "High, Medium and Low" in the middle of each square of the grid? (As you can see on my original drawing)

Here is what I have done so far:

```latex
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=both,ymin=0,ymax=8,xmax=8,xmin=0,xtick={2,4,6},xticklabels={Low,Middle, High},ytick={2,4,6}, yticklabels={Low,Middle, High},xlabel= Classical counterpart,ylabel=Quantization]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The short answer is that, yes, this is possible *but* I have to warn you that questions of the form "Please draw this for me" that show no effort on the part of OP, often don't get answered. You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). A quick search on TeX.SX for drawing functions (with tikz or pstricks) will give you an idea of where to start from.

Comment: Thank you very much @Andrew, I perfectly understand and I actually already did something. I updated my question :)  and added the code that I tried to run.

Comment: Perhaps there can be found the best suitable solution for your problem if you could say something about the actually data you want to show. E.g. if there is only one data point for a category couple (=Low/Low) i think a matrix plot (pgfplots doc v1.17 -> section 4.5.16) should be of interest to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps there is a more elegant solution. Here I used a style for the labels and I shifted the labels by trial and error.

I anchored the `xtick` to the **north** (middle of the upper edge of the label) and the `ytick` to the **east** (middle of the right edge of the label).

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=both,ymin=0,ymax=6,xmax=6,xmin=0,xtick={2,4,6},xticklabels={Low,Middle, High},ytick={2,4,6}, yticklabels={Low,Middle, High},xlabel= Classical counterpart,ylabel=Quantization,every x tick label/.style={xshift=-12mm,anchor=north},every y tick label/.style={yshift=-8mm,anchor=east}]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It helps a lot :) I just upgraded your code a bit as I do not need to have the last column and row

Comment: I just have small question now, how can I add points with label in my plot?

Comment: What points do you want to add?

Comment: Let's say I want to add the following points:

A: (1.5;1) - label: "HHL" & B: (3;3) - label: "VQC"

Comment: With `\addplot` it seems to me!

Comment: But what if I just want to have individual points without lines connecting them?

Comment: `\addplot [only marks]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111497/discussion-between-buenogrande-and-andrec).