# Add Colored rectangle & text on a Plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

My question is a follow-up question from [Drawing a XY axis with categories](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557552/drawing-a-xy-axis-with-categories)

I would like to draw three squares on my plot:

- The most bottom one should be green,
- The middle one orange
- The highest one red.

It would be fantastic if I could add a text in the middle of each square of the same color.

Here is what I have so far:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[nodes near coords, grid=both, ymin=0,ymax=6,xmax=6,xmin=0,
xtick={2,4,6},xticklabels={Low,Middle, High},
ytick={2,4,6}, yticklabels={Low,Middle, High},
xlabel= Classical counterpart,ylabel=Quantization,
every x tick label/.style={xshift=-11mm,anchor=north},
every y tick label/.style={yshift=-8mm,anchor=east}
]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2); %green
\draw (2,2) rectangle (4,4); %orange
\draw (4,4) rectangle (6,6); %red
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update 1

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[nodes near coords, grid=both, ymin=0,ymax=6,xmax=6,xmin=0,
xtick={2,4,6},xticklabels={Low,Middle, High},
ytick={2,4,6}, yticklabels={Low,Middle, High},
xlabel= Classical counterpart,ylabel=Quantization,
every x tick label/.style={xshift=-11mm,anchor=north},
every y tick label/.style={yshift=-8mm,anchor=east}
]
\draw[green] (0,0) rectangle (2,2)node[midway]{green};
\draw[orange] (2,2) rectangle (4,4)node[midway]{orange};
\draw[red] (4,4) rectangle (6,6)node[midway]{red};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The command to only color *(without drawing the edges of the figure)* is `\fill` To write a text, it is `\node`.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[nodes near coords, grid=both, ymin=0,ymax=6,xmax=6,xmin=0,
xtick={2,4,6},xticklabels={Low,Middle, High},
ytick={2,4,6}, yticklabels={Low,Middle, High},
xlabel= Classical counterpart,ylabel=Quantization,
every x tick label/.style={xshift=-11mm,anchor=north},
every y tick label/.style={yshift=-8mm,anchor=east}
]
\fill[green] (0,0) rectangle (2,2)node[midway,text=blue]{green};
\fill[orange] (2,2) rectangle (4,4)node[midway,text=cyan]{orange};
\fill[red] (4,4) rectangle (6,6)node[midway,text=violet]{red};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry I expressed myself not clearly. Is it possible to only color the borders of each square?

Comment: @BuenoGrande replace `\fill` with `\draw`

Comment: @jsbibra Huh? what?

Comment: @BuenoGrande done !

Comment: Oh thank you so much @AndréC ! It is perfect. 

One small question, is it possible to have a darker green ?

Comment: Yes, replace the colour with `green!80!black` or `green!70!black`, etc.